# numpy.loadtxt -> could not convert string to float: '-0,0118'

Tags: arrays, numpy, plot

When I try to run this code:

```
x,y = np.genfromtxt('Diode_A_Upcd.txt', unpack = True,  delimiter = ';' )
```

I get this:
[Array Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lsBg5.png)
My data:
[Diode_A_Upcd.txt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lKof4.png)

I would like to store each row in individual arrays in order to then plot them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message is due to the string being `0,0118`.  Numpy needs floats to be `0.0118`, decimal point not a decimal comma. `np.loadtxt` has an optional argument `converters` to allow a function to convert strings in one format to another.

```
import numpy as np                                                                                               

test_string = [ '0,123;5,234', '0,789;123,45']

def translate( s ): 
    s = s.replace( b',', b'.' ) 
    return s 

conv = { 0: translate, 1: translate } 
# Apply translate to both columns.
                                                                                                   
result = np.loadtxt( test_string, delimiter = ';', converters = conv )

result
#  array([[1.2300e-01, 5.2340e+00],
#         [7.8900e-01, 1.2345e+02]])
```

Comment: `pandas.read_csv` accepts a `decimal` parameter with this flexibility.

Comment: It worked, but now I would like to store the first and second row in two different array and the code:  t = result[:0] doesn't work

Comment: Does `t = result[0]` work?  Without the colon.  Or `t=result[:, 0]` to get a column.

Comment: No it didn't, but now it worked, thank you guys